# checkedlistbox addition with other numbers

Tags: c#, listbox, sum, checkedlistbox

It's my first post.
I'm trying to make multiple sums in a checkedlistbox in Visual C#. There are 108 numbers, one in each row, and I'm trying to sum the checked item(s) with each one of the rest and print it in a textbox.

I have done this, but I think it's incorrect.
This actually does the sum, but also with the number itself and the whole thing 108 times

I want to add the checked number with the rest numbers in the checkbox.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   foreach(string checkednumber in checkedlistbox1.CheckedItems)
   {
      double x = Convert.ToDouble(checkednumber);

      double a = 0;
      for (double y = 0; y < checkedlistbox1.Items.Count; ++y)
      {
         foreach (string othernumbers in checkedlistbox1.Items)
         {
            double z = Convert.ToDouble(othernumbers);
            sum = x + z;
            string str = Convert.ToString(sum);
            listbox1.Items.Add(str);
         }
      }
   }  
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: So you think it's incorrect. Why? What behavior are you seeing?

Comment: I have no doubt that this is incorrect, though, as for some reason you have a double nested loop, looping over the same items repeatedly and so some really odd things with `x`, `a`, and `z` (you need to choose better names for variables).

Comment: OP? Any input on my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just want to sum the numbers for items that are checked?

```
double sum = 0;

foreach(object checkedItem in checkedlistbox1.CheckedItems)
{
    try 
    {
        sum += Convert.ToDouble(checkedItem.ToString()); 
    }
    catch (FormatException e) {} //catch exception where checkedItem is not a number

    listbox1.Items.Add(sum.ToString());
}
```

Your question is incredibly unclear, I'm not really sure if this is what you want at all.

Comment: OP also seems confused why he has so many results being outputted - probably worth including the adding of the result to `listbox1` to help with that

Comment: @VisualMelon Yeah, probably because he's got it inside 3 loops hahah. I'll add that.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use linq to achieve it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var result = from num in this.checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.OfType<string>()
                         select Convert.ToInt32(num);
            this.textBox1.Text = result.Sum().ToString();
        }
    }
}
```